# PDF or CDF of product of two independant random variables

Tags: probability, statistics, characteristic-functions

I'm looking for a formula for computing the PDF (I would prefer the CDF if possible) of the product of two independent random variables.

I found the Mellin integral/transform is the analytical solution, but is there a practical/robust way  to numerically compute this ?

In fact, my main preocupation is dealing with sums and products of independent random variables, so if there is any other method, I will appreciate too ; for example, I know that the Mellin transform of the product is the product of th eMellin transforms, and the characteristic function of the sum is the product of the characteristic functions, but with that I can not find the CDF of the sum of the product of two independent random variables ($Z = X\times Y + U\times V$ where $X,Y,U$ and $V$ are independent)

Comment: You will have that the law of $Z$ is the convolution of the laws of $XY$ and $UV.$ To fin these laws, take logarithms, since $\log(XY) = \log(X) + \log(Y),$ its law is the convolution of the laws of $\log(X)$ and $\log(Y).$ It'll be a messy formula.

Comment: If the random variables are non-negative, then you might say $F_{XY}(z)$ $=P(XY \le z)$ $=\int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}\int\limits_{y=0}^{z/x} f_Y(y)f_X(x) \, dy \,dx $ $=\int\limits_{x=0}^{\infty}F_Y(\frac zx) f_X(x)\,dx $

Comment: @WilliamM. I've thought about taking the logarithm but wasn't able to find any reference/explaination about this method ; in fact I always find the Mellin integration method, which makes me wonder if the trick was as simple as taking the logarithm, I presume I would see this method everywhere, so is there any caveat to taking the log ?

Comment: @Henry And do you know any algorithmic method to implement this ?

Comment: You need to do some integration, so the practical ease of doing this depends on the particular functions involved.  Or if you can simulate $X$ and $Y$ then you can simulate $XY$ and get a good estimate quickly

Comment: For the logarithms to work, you need everything to be positive a.s.

Comment: @WilliamM. Everything or just the product (can both random variables be strictly negative) ? And if the variables do not satisfy this condition, is there a way to handle their product anyway ?